# Please specify the "data" property

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.15
My view displays the error above. I don't know why. but here's the detail:

My Controller:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
            // cek login admin
            IsAuth::Admin();
            // panggil function loadModel() dan tampung ke $dataOrder
            $dataOrder = $this->loadModel($id);
            //find data ConfirmPayment berdasarkan order_code
            $dataConfirmPayment = ConfirmPayment::model()->findByAttributes(array('order_code' => $dataOrder->order_code));
            // find data alamat pengiriman berdasarkan address_id
            $dataConfirmPayment = Address::model()->findByPk($dataOrder->address_id);
            // panggil model Orderdetail & function search
            $model = new Orderdetail('search');
            // clear any default values
            $model->unsetAttributes();
            // set select data order_detail berdasarkan order_code
            $model->order_code = $dataOrder->order_code;
            // render ke orders view
    $this->render('view',array(
                'model' => $dataOrder,
                'ordet' => $model,
                'dataPayment' => $dataConfirmPayment,
                'shippingAddress' => $dataShippingAddress,
            ));
}
```

My view:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    /*data alamat pengiriman*/
    'data'=>$shippingAddress,
    'attributes'=>array(
        array(
            'type'=>'HTML',
            'name'=>'name',
            'value'=>$shippingAddress->name,
        ),
    ),
```

Hopefuly I described my question better.

Comment: The `data` property of the `CDetailView` is `null`, since you did not any value to the `$dataShippingAddress` variable in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies here

```
//find data ConfirmPayment berdasarkan order_code
            $dataConfirmPayment = ConfirmPayment::model()->findByAttributes(array('order_code' => $dataOrder->order_code));
            // find data alamat pengiriman berdasarkan address_id
            $dataConfirmPayment = Address::model()->findByPk($dataOrder->address_id);
```

You are assigning value to **$dataConfirmPayment** twice.

The second variable should be **$dataShippingAddress**

i.e

```
//find data ConfirmPayment berdasarkan order_code
            $dataConfirmPayment = ConfirmPayment::model()->findByAttributes(array('order_code' => $dataOrder->order_code));
            // find data alamat pengiriman berdasarkan address_id
            $dataShippingAddress= Address::model()->findByPk($dataOrder->address_id);
```